# Repository Pattern in C#

Tags: c#, .net, repository-pattern

I am trying to figure out the repository pattern for .NET.  I think I have a pretty decent understanding of it, but I still don't feel comfortable using it.

I have googled for this topic, but found some advanced topics along with the repository pattern.  What I am looking for is a basic knowledge of the concept, then I can build on it.  With that said, can I get a recommendation of some good articles on the repository pattern?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the answers to [Repository pattern tutorial in C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20100914212618/http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions/3175/repository-pattern-tutorial-in-c).

Comment: Voted to close this question as off-topic (reason: find off-site resource). The linked question in this answer has been deleted (possibly for the same reason).

Answer (score 5):

I recommend start by [Fowler's definition](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)

This [concrete implementation](https://web.archive.org/web/20210115232305/http://geekswithblogs.net/AndrewSiemer/archive/2008/02/05/linq-to-sql---implementing-the-repository-pattern.aspx) could help you as well : )

Answer (score 2):

Ayende's [Rhino.Commons](https://web.archive.org/web/20100328002538/http://www.ayende.com:80/wiki/Rhino%20Commons.ashx) has a decent implementation.

I also benefitted from reading "Domain-Driven Design" by Eric Evans, which gives a good foundation of understanding the motivations behind Repository.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at following Article.

- [**Using the Repository Software Design
  Pattern**](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-29-cs.aspx)

  If you go through the whole series above, will be more help full

Answer (score 0):

I'm in exactly the same position you were in.  I found this Remondo.net blog post particularly useful.  It walks through the implementation of a basic repository:

[The Repository Pattern Example in C#](http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/)